# How to generate a symbol table for a Pascal-subset compiler in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, pascal, symbols

I'm writing a compiler in C, which will interpret pseudo-Pascal instructions (their syntax is for now irrelevant) to an `asm` output. What I know for now, is that I need:

- a **syntax scanner** which will scan the user input and identify tokens for the parser to process
- a **parser** which will check if those tokens fit into the defined grammar productions
- a **symbol table**

I'm a little bit stuck on the most important phase - symbol table. 
I'm unsure as to what should be included in this table. Certainly any variables (identifiers), with their address. Should I include keywords such as `if`, `for` etc? Any guidelines on this would be appreciated.

For now, I think the most logical way would be to define a structure:

```
struct entry{
    char* name;
    Vartype vartype;
    int address;
}
```

where `Vartype` is an enum with available variable types (`integer` and `real`). Then ofc I would make an array of structures and expand it when necessary. How and when should I modify it?

Comment: Read a good book about compiler construction (e.g. N. Wirth,). That subject should be handled there.

Comment: Why don't you look in a production Pascal compiler source like http://www.freepascal.org? You will need a symbol table per scope though, since visibility requires looking up an identifier from inner to outer (global) scope). See symbase unit (ble unit http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/compiler/symtable.pas?view=markup and  ) and symtable (for the more specialized ones)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awsome free book: [Compiler design in C](http://www.holub.com/software/compilerDesignInC.pdf)

Comment: This should be a comment, even if it is a good one

Comment: Unable to comment yet, except my own answers!

Comment: You *cannot* post answers because you can't comment. Earn the rep to comment, and you'll have that privilege. The area marked **Your Answer** is for just that (answers). Using it inappropriately to bypass not having a privilege is against the guidelines, and can get your account suspended or banned. (In addition, it can get you downvotes, which will cost you the reputation you need to get the ability to post comments and other privileges.) We also do not accept answers that consist of nothing but a link to an off-site resource.